# Multiple Async workers, work returned in order

Tags: c#, asynchronous, worker

What I'm trying to do:

Send an individual Queue from MasterQueue each to their own async worker

Wait for all async workers to finish and return results

Order results in same order as they were in the MasterQueue

```
<Queue<Queue<object[]>> MasterQueue = new Queue<Queue<object[]>>();

while (MasterQueue.Count > 0)
{

 Queue<object[]> Queue = MasterQueue.Dequeue();

 //Send Queue to an Async Worker for processing...
 //Lets say 5 in total that finish randomly so 3, 2, 5, 4, 1

}

//Wait for all 5 Async workers to finish and return their work, then use the work in original order...

//Use work from 1
//Use work from 2
//Use work from 3
//Use work from 4
//Use work from 5
```

Comment: Dequeue happens in order, so just increment a counter and use that to reorder the completed at the end - or, can the TPL (Enumerable/Parallel) methods to take care of this directly?

Comment: You may want to look into [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of Tasks (one Task per async worker) and use Task.WaitAll(tasks) on the tasks.  The order of the tasks will be the same as the order of the list/array.

Something like:

```
while (masterQueue.Count > 0)
{
    Queue<object[]> queue = masterQueue.Dequeue();

    //Send Queue to an async Worker for processing...
    tasks.Add(Process(queue));
}

// tasks are already in order
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

...
async static Task Process(Queue<object[]> queue)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });
}
```